# Rest Controller POST method getting called twice from angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I know this has been discussed in many questions but I still didn't get my answer. Ours is a strange and intermittent issue. Our service call works fine when we test it in local eclipse. But on server it occurs intermittently for some users that the submit method is triggered twice. We have loggers and we see that both methods go successfully but we don't want that. The recent issue came on Microsoft edge but also sometimes occurs on Mozilla Firefox.

This is the service call from angular.

.ts

```
this.service.performActionForCreation(this.requestList, this.loggedUser, action, this.role).subscribe(
          (response: any) => {
            console.log(response)
            this.showSpinner = false;
            if (response) {
              this._alert.open("Requests approved succesfully!", 'Cancel', {
                duration: 3000
              })
             
            }
            else {
              this.showSpinner = false;
              this._alert.open("Unable to approve requests!", 'OK', {
                duration: 3000
              })
            }
          }
```

service class

```
 performActionForCreation(requestList, user, action, role){
    let params = new HttpParams().set("action",action).set("user",user).set("role", role);
    return this.http.post(this.baseurl+'/trackRequest/performActionForCreation',requestList,{ params })
  }
```

Post request controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/id")
public class IdController {

@PostMapping("/create")
    public boolean createRequest(@RequestBody UserIdDetails request, @RequestParam("user") String user) {
        logger.info(" Starting createRequest method in IdController" + request + "user" + user);
        boolean result = idService.createRequest(request, user);
        logger.info("Request " + request);
        return result;
    }
}
```

We have added these CORS annotations in our main class

Comment: Where are you unsubscribing?

Comment: Try to put some logs on the client side as well, find the actual place where the second unwanted request is triggered. P.S.: You don't need to unsubscribe from observables that HttpClient creates. They are cold observables and they complete after emitting the first value, so no risk of memory leaks there.

Comment: Is it possible that your users double click the submit button? Add some debounce or disable the button while the request is pending

Comment: Yes, the unsubscribing isn't needed that is why we haven't added it. We disable the submit button once it is clicked so there is no chance of it getting clicked twice.

Comment: My angular html component had an issue, post request was triggered on a function which was being called once on the button click and the second time on the form submission.